# OData with protobuf

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, odata-v4

I would like to use Web API 2 / OData with [protobuf](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net).
There are several articles on how to get the Web API service to use protocol buffers but I can't seem to find any that talk about how to get the OData client libraries to deserialize on the client.
https://www.infoworld.com/article/2982579/application-architecture/working-with-protocol-buffers-in-web-api.html
https://damienbod.com/2014/01/11/using-protobuf-net-media-formatter-with-web-api-2/

I'm pretty sure I need to do something inside the OData SendingRequest / ReceivingResponse events but I can't seem to find any articles on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but TIL this was a thing - and using my lib too! (both articles)

Comment: @MarcGravell I see that you worked on the protobuf-net project. Protobuf-net is a nice library. OData is also nice but has very limited information for the client side. (Not your fault)...